# Does Nepal have open borders with India?

Tags: india, borders, nepal

According to Wikipedia, Nepal has "[open borders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_border)" with India underneath the [1950 Indo-Nepal Treaty of Peace and Friendship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_Indo-Nepal_Treaty_of_Peace_and_Friendship).

As far as I understand, it's not a *truly* open border as movement is restricted to Indian Citizens *only*.

By truly open border I mean, for instance, the Vatican City and Italy wherein *anyone* allowed entry into Italy is legally allowed into Vatican City even though the microstate is not a part of the Schengen Area or the EU.

Comment: You've left out a possibility. I regard a border as being open whether I need a visa or not and as being closed if I can't cross it even if I have a valid visa. For example the Laos/Burma border is closed to non-Lao non-Burmese nationals even if they have a valid visa.

Comment: @hippietrail Quite interesting. Did not know that this was a possibility!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its open only for Indian or Nepalese citizens. Its not open for citizens of other countries.

[This is a Nepalese link](http://www.nepalembassy.in/visa.htm) which says Indian citizen entering Nepal should have proper identity to prove that they are valid Indian citizens, that means no need of visa.

And [this is a link from Indian Embassy in Nepal](http://www.indianembassy.org.np/index1.php?option=e6r5wlVM8od_u8Y0CdwsDiTfg0cohLLpEcNS8hphu-0&id=qRHrJpTWA-lU7m-mgRK0-mH1B726RLWYI5JIPiux4I0). On first line it says:

> #### Introductory Information
>
> Except Bhutan & Nepal Nationals all foreign nationals including children MUST obtain a visa to travel to India.

Hope this helps

And if you are travelling on a car or bikes or any means of transport from one country to another between India and Nepal, you have to make an entry at border check point but its always wise to get a letter(like No objection Letter for a car, bike) from respective embassy from current country.

Comment: can you add some references?

Comment: Reference can be found in the question itself.. there is a link to wikipedia..

Comment: @SunJ Is there any other **official** link you know of to verify this?

Comment: @AdityaSomani I've edited my answer, you can have a look.

Comment: I rendered your links in-line and used the appropriate environment for quotes. Feel free to rollback. :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, an American, for example, need a visa to enter Nepal, which is not really what I would consider an "open border".  *Most* countries allow some neighbors in without a visa (all the ASEAN countries, the US and Canada, the EU, etc.)

Comment: Why do they still call it open borders then? If you take a look at the wiki article, it is specially mentioned there in the same manner as the EU. Why are the other countries as you mentioned not indicated in the list but India and Nepal are?

Comment: @AdityaSomani because US citizens cannot stay in Canada for an unlimited amount of time (and vice versa). It's not really an open border.

Comment: Care to add a reference for your claims?

Comment: @JoErNanO http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/42167/9009

Comment: @JonathanReez Thanks, great answer! I meant Malvoglio, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes Nepal has open borders with India, but it is only valid for Nepalese and Indian people. 
So it means citizen of either countries don't need passport and visa to enter each other's countries but they might need to show citizenship or other identity on ask.

Answer (score 1):

India and Nepal have had free movement of people starting [back in 1950](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_Indo-Nepal_Treaty_of_Peace_and_Friendship). According to the treaty, there are are almost no restrictions on visiting, buying property, opening a company, etc. Foreign citizens aren't included in the scope of the agreement and the two countries remain fully separate in the eyes of most tourists.

The border between Vatican City and Italy is not 100% open - you can technically get a visa to visit the Vatican, but not Italy. Likewise Schengen countries sometimes issue [Limited Territorial Validity](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-types/) visas, which are only accepted in one country. The border between the UK and Ireland is also not 100% open - each country issues it's own national visas, which aren't always accepted in the neighbouring country.

Similarly Canadians can only stay [up to 180 days](http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/information-for-canadians.html) in the US, unless they extend their visa. Neither are Canadian/US tourist visas mutually recognized, nor is there a right to free movement between the two states. Nevertheless it's the longest [undefended border](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada%E2%80%93United_States_border) in the world.